# Splitting light into colors, mathematical expression (Fourier transforms)

Tags: visible-light, fourier-transform, wave-particle-duality

I am trying to solve a problem that includes a function of the light hitting a certain area. My question is, how would I change a function $G(x)$ of photons hitting a certain area to include just photons of a certain wavelength, say red light. I feel like this could be accomplished using a Fourier transform and de Broglie's law, but I'm not sure. Can someone please help, just for a general Gaussian function $G(x)$?

More information: Basically, given a function that gives the number of photons hitting a certain area, I want a mathematical way to determine how many of those photons are of a specific frequency (such as red light).

$G(x)$ is defined as the integral in a gaussian slit experiment (that is, a double slit experiment with the path integral of a gaussian probability) such as in Feynmann's Path Integrals and Quantum Mechanics or in [arXiv:1110.2346](https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.2346).

Comment: Can you give more detail on your problem? As it stands I can't figure out what you're trying to do.

Comment: If you know the frequency of the light you want, just use a band pass filter http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band-pass_filter on the original dataset.

Comment: It doesn't sound like filtering or fourier transforms are at all relevant here. Just multiply (total number of photons) * (fraction of photons that are red) = (number of red photons). [The filtering or fourier transforms would be used if you only knew the electric field as a function of time, but it doesn't sound like that's the case. It sounds like you know the rate of photons as a function of position.] Don't make a simple thing complicated!

Comment: @tpg2114 Thanks for the response. This is what I want to do, but I want to know a way to do it mathematically, not with a device

Comment: @Steve B Thanks for the response. How do you determine mathematically the "fraction of photons that are red?" Also, what do you mean by the "electric field as a function of time?"

Comment: @JamesYu-tai Look up convolution, it's how to do it mathematically.

Comment: @tpg2114 What function will he use to convolve his Gaussian? I could be missing something, but as best I can tell from the wording of the question, $G(x)$ doesn't contain any info about the frequency content of the photons he's modelling, so he has to force the info in somehow. If there is a specific hardware configuration behind all of this then maybe we can make progress by looking up the spectral content of the light sources, properties of the media through which the light travels, etc, but $G(x)$ by itself is not enough.

Comment: @cb3 I agree, there's not enough information to adequately answer this. I tried earlier and it was downvoted so I deleted it, I'll add it back in once I can address the reasons it was downvoted. Until then, the best I can do is point him in the direction he seems to think he wants to go. At least until one of us learns how to read minds :)

Comment: @JamesYu-tai So what exactly are you recording? What data do you have? How is it measured?

Comment: @tpg2114 I know what a convolution is. Good to know that this is how you do it, but would a Gaussian Slit Experiment (for example) meet the requirements for G(x) as "electric field as a function of time?"

Comment: @cb3 Sorry for the delay. I edited the question to include that G(x) is defined as the integral in a gaussian slit experiment such as in Feynmann's Path Integrals and Quantum Mechanics or in arxiv.org/pdf/1110.2346.

Comment: @JamesYu-tai You want to "do it mathematically, not with a device" bandpassfilter. Than look up the spectral distribution of your light source and the [Transmission curve](http://www.thorlabs.de/NewGroupPage9.cfm?ObjectGroup_ID=873) (click on tutorial) of your bandpassfilter for red. Having this allows answering your question.